# Getting swatch value from checkout_cart_product_add_before observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, mini-cart

Is it possible to get the Swatch **value id** or **name** from the `checkout_cart_product_add_before` observer? I've passed the Product using

```
$product = $observer->getProduct();
$productId = $observer->getProduct()->getId();
```

but I can't find anywhere online on how to get the swatch value or child id of the saved product, currently, it only passes the **configurableID** and I need the Simple id. Looping through the associated products is no good as I need the one that was selected

Answer (score 1):

In your observer, you can get the child product data using this code.

```
    $info = $observer->getInfo();
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    if ($product->getTypeId() == "configurable") {
        $configClass = $product->getTypeInstance();
        $childProduct = $configClass->getProductByAttributes($info['super_attribute'], $product);
        $sku = $childProduct->getSku();
        $productId = $childProduct->getId();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In event 'checkout_cart_product_add_before' arguments are as below as $product and $request. You can get the swatch value from $request variable.

```
 Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_before', array(
             'product' => $product,
              'request' => $request
        ));
```